# XAMPP and WAMPserver

Tags: windows-8, xampp, wamp

I have been using Wamp with Windows 7 and when I recently upgraded to Windows 8 I have been unable to connect to the localhost. Uninstalling and reinstalling does not work. I also tried to install XAMPP to see if I can use the localhost on there but no. What is it about Windows 8 that is preventing me from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a beta version of Xampp(1.8.1)thats available for download.Here is the Link
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html. Check if it works or not..

Answer (score 1):

The problem come because Windows 8 integrated Microsoft IIS, and both WAMP and IIS use port
80.
Find below how to fix it (the solution come from  http://wpfirstaid.com/2012/11/wamp-server-microsoft-iis-windows-8-pro/ , so check the url for complete explaination):

> Click on the WAMP Server system tray icon and follow this path to the first file to be edited: Apache -> httpd.conf
>   Search for “Listen 80″ and change this to “Listen 8080″ (You can use most any number; 8080 is a common alternative in this case.)
>   Locate the file wampmanager.tpl (generally found in the default folder: C:\wamp) and open it with your text editor.
>   Search for any instance of the parameter “http://localhost/” and replace it with “http://localhost:8080/” (or the same number you used above.)
>
> Now, Right-click the WAMP Server icon in the system tray and click Refresh and you should be able to work with both localhost environments: "http://localhost:8080/" with the WAMP Server; and, "http://localhost.com/" with the Microsoft-IIS services.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that windows 8  has anything to do with it, can you check your firewall , if its causing this problem. because in earlier windows versions. many people with firewalls have this problem. If the problem still persists then maybe i will install wamp and try it on my own windows 8.